# Webservices invalid SOAP header

Tags: .net, web-services, asmx

I have a GUID & token to be passed whenever a webmethod (webservice) is called, from client app that is consuming the webservice.

1. Client app throws an "Error:undefined" javascript error & it gives this as exception when viewed via firebug.

   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:

   Invalid GUID Header.

   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapMessage.RunExtensions(SoapExtension[] extensions, Boolean thrownException) at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.CreateServerInstance() at

   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke() at

   System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcesSRequest()

Any idea?

```
  [SessionValidationCheck]
  [SoapHeader("SessionEntry")]
  [WebMethod]
```

Before each web method i decorate with a session GUID & header value.

Thanks.

Comment: I would guess your client is not sending a header. Please show the calling code.